# How do I remove comments from inside a "script" element but not the rest of the HTML?

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, comments

How do I only target comments inside of script elements, instead of all "double slash" comments, for example, this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">Link to example.com</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // I am a comment, I describe this script
  console.log("Hello World!");
</script>
```

Becomes this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">Link to example.com</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("Hello World!");
</script>
```

So far I have this:

```
html = re.sub(re.compile(r"\/\/.*?\n"), "\n", html)
```

It works but it also removes my links in my `href` and `src` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) of *regex*. So, the following code should do it :

```
html = re.sub(re.compile(r"(?<!:)\/\/.*\n"), "\n", html)
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4GKEC6/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've modified it a bit to get this `(?<![ps]\:)\/\/.*\n` it works perfect now. Once again, thanks +1.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate your script tags:

```
scripts = bs4_obj.find_all('script')
for script in script:
    # Your regex
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this answer makes sense but unfortunately I'm not using BeautifulSoup for this project. None the less, this is a great answer +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
comments_match = r"[^:]\/\/.+\r?\n" 
print( re.sub(comments_match, "\n", your_html_string) )
```

See info on negated character classes - http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this, but it doesn't work the way I need it to, either ways, thanks +1.